# sails -mongo : many to many relationship is not working in my app. followed the documentation still its giving empty array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sails.js, sails-mongo

I am using sails js with mongodb.

here is my EventTags model:

EventTags.js

```
module.exports = {

schema: true,

  attributes: {

          eventList: {
                collection: 'Events', 
                via:'tagList'

            },  

            event_tag_name:{ type:'string',
                 required:true,
                 unique:true
            }
  }
};
```

here is my Events Model:

Events.js

```
module.exports = {


    schema: true,

  attributes: {

        tagList: {
                collection: 'EventTags', 
                via:'eventList'  
            }, 

        title:{ type:'string',required: true},

        blurb:{ type:'string'},

        description:{ type:'string'},

        venue: {type: 'string',required: true},
    }
};
```

created the EventTags and here is my json response.

```
{

    "status": 109,
    "status_message": "success..!!",

    "event_tag_info": {

        "event_tag_name": "travel1",
        "createdAt": "2015-07-15T06:01:09.050Z",
        "updatedAt": "2015-07-15T06:01:09.050Z",
        "id": "55a5f725f7d707ba4f32ac74"
    }
}
```

next i copied the EventTags ID i.e.**"id": "55a5f725f7d707ba4f32ac74**" . 
to Events Model.
here is Events Model Post Data.

```
{

    "tagList":"55a5f725f7d707ba4f32ac74",

    "title": "Snow City : Bengaluru", 

    "blurb": "testtesttesttesttesttest", 

    "description": "Toronto has been chosene city",

    "venue": "palace ground" 

}
```

---

when i hit http://localhost:1337/events

I am getting empty tagList array.

```
[

  {

      tagList: [ ], 
      title: "Snow City ", 
      blurb: "some data",
      description: "some data", 
      venue: "some address", 
      id: "55a5f98ef7d707ba4f32ac75"
  }

]
```

Please Can Anyone Help Me With This.

Answer (score 1):

Many-to-many relation means that a join table will be auto created by Sails. So you need to assotiate data in two tables to each other.

First of all. In models all *via* names are in lower case:

**EventTags.js**

```
module.exports = {

schema: false,

  attributes: {

          eventList: {
                collection: 'Events', 
                via:'taglist'

            },  

            event_tag_name:{ 
                 type:'string',
                 required:true,
                 unique:true
            }
  }
};
```

**Events.js**

```
module.exports = {


    schema: false,

    attributes: {

        tagList: {
                collection: 'EventTags', 
                via:'eventlist'  
            }, 

        title:{ type:'string',required: true},

        blurb:{ type:'string'},

        description:{ type:'string'},

        venue: {type: 'string',required: true},
    }
};
```

Next you need to associate data like:

```
Events.findOne({id: '55a5f98ef7d707ba4f32ac75'}).exec(function(err, event){
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        event.tagList.add('55a5f725f7d707ba4f32ac74');
        event.save(function(err, saved){
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log(saved);
            }    
        });
    }    
});
```

Also you can use Blueprint to save data like:

Create data - POST /events

```
{
    tagList: [ '55a5f725f7d707ba4f32ac74' ], 
    title: "Snow City ", 
    blurb: "some data",
    description: "some data", 
    venue: "some address", 
}
```

Update data - PUT /events/55a5f98ef7d707ba4f32ac75

```
{
    tagList: [ '55a5f725f7d707ba4f32ac74' ], 
    title: "Snow City ", 
    blurb: "some data",
    description: "some data", 
    venue: "some address", 
}
```

Related [documentation](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/many-to-many)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i tried your procedure and again it giving me a empty list as 'taglist'.  i tried many to many relationship with category model, article model and tags, it works fine for category, articles and tags and when i included the event model, there it is not working.

Comment: yeah.. i am sure bulkin.

Comment: i followed the same procedure for my other models i.e. category, articles and tags, there its working fine. i followed the same procedure for events and tags and it is not working.  i tried creating new model 'EventTags' model and tried the many to many relationship with 'Events' model, again same problem taglist[ ].

Comment: That means, you have an error somewhere in your code. How do you associate EventTags to Events? Through Blueprint API?

Comment: i checked all my code, i don't have any error in my code and i corrected my faults as you shown above. and i associated the EventTags and Events as you shown above.

Comment: I updated association code with error handling and saved result debug. Try it and show what it prints to console.

Comment: okay.. i'll check bulkin..!! and thanks for your suggestions :)

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the tag list of an event, you'll need to populate the `tagList` attribute.

Using the [Blueprint API](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/blueprint-api/populate-where) you can hit http://localhost:1337/events/55a5f98ef7d707ba4f32ac75/tagList.

In a controller, you'd use:

```
Event
  .findOne('55a5f98ef7d707ba4f32ac75')
  .populate('tagList')
  .exec(...);
```

Comment: i tried that too yann still it is not working. i have relationship like this -- category has N to N relationship with articles and vice versa and articles has N to N relationship with Tags and vice versa and when i included the N to N relationship with Events and Tags, there it is showing empty array of tag list.